# call java function from JSP page's button on click event

Tags: java, function, jsp, button, call

There is an application that stores photos in oracle db (oracle multimedia format). There is a JAVA servlet page that handle the connection and the SQLs ..., and there are JSP pages to show the images in browser.

There is a delete function in the JAVA page, when i click one thumbnail it navigates to the an other JSP and show the full size image. Here i would like to call the 
`public void deleteRowById( String selectId )` function which is in the JAVA servlet page. i would like to use a button, and i'm not realy know what is the proper way to call this function.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: On click submit to a servlet with query string like "deleteRow" and in servlet check if request parameter is deleteRow and then call deleteRowById method

Comment: Once you have navigated to a new page the previous js context is unloaded, so what you describe is not an `onclick` event. Looks like more an `onload` event (or better, some internal logic of the destination JSP/Servlet)

Comment: Maybe i have not explained the issue properly. Once i navigated to the jsp page that show a full size image, it is the result of a select. in this page i have the id of the image, the full size image shown, and there is a delete button. and yes maybe this shouldn't an onclick event i would like to call my deleteRowById function from the java servlet file by clicing the button. The JSP area is very new to me that's why i would be happy with an explanation or maybe a very short example.

Comment: If you want to call a method in the server (Java or other technology) without reloading the page, the best option is AJAX (plenty of info out there). There are other options (opening an external window that closes itself, communication through an applet) but AJAX is the best one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the mean time i solved the situation. There is a java class that contains SQL statements -taht's what i would like to call with a form button.

1st JSP page show the button like delete, it navigates to an other JSP page via passing a parameter with post method, in this 2nd JSP page i call the main java class method that execute a delete statement then from the 2nd JSP page i navigate back with `<jsp:forward page="1st_page.jsp"/>`

Maybe not a cutting edge solution but works like charm :)